# Квадратный корень в Python

Tags: python

```
import math
def psq():
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    c = int(input())
    a1 = int(input())
    b1 = int(input())
    c1 = int(input())
    p = float((a + b + c) / 3)
    p2 = float((a1 + b1 + c1) / 3)
    s = p + p2
    sq = (p * (p - a)(p - b)(p - c)) ** 0.5 + (p2 * (p2 - a1)(p2 - b1)(p2 - c1)) ** 0.5
    print(s, ' - периметр, ', sq, ' - площадь')
psq()
```

Вот код и в строке где корень все время вылазает ошибка на счет  типа данных.
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: А ошибку предлагаете угадывать? :) Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка `править` под вопросом)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А знаки арифметическмх операций кто за вас будет ставить?

```
sq = (p * (p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)) ** 0.5 + (p2 * (p2 - a1)*(p2 - b1)*(p2 - c1)) ** 0.5
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, совсем забыл